# What could cause a disabled Windows service to become re-enabled?

Tags: windows, service, coldfusion

I have a dev and test Windows2003 Server, and on both of which I'm upgrading ColdFusion from version 8 to version 10.

The differences between the two versions mean that I can install 10 alongside 8, with the intention of uninstalling CF8 if all goes well (so far so good).

On my Test server I have a weird issue though.  When I stop and disable the CF8 services, they seem to switch themselves back to "Automatic" and automatically start up when I'm not looking.  This happens after a period of time, (maybe an hour or two) and not simply following a logon/off.

I've checked that there are no scheduled tasks within CF10 or the Windows task scheduler, looked at the CF8 logs, and even checked the Windows logs for others logging on and winding me up, but there's nothing that I can see that would cause this.

Of course, I could simply uninstall CF8, but I'm naturally curious.  Any ideas what to try next to find out why these services seem to be taking on a life of their own?

Answer (score 6):

This can occur if it is configured in Group Policy or gpedit.msc.